# Checkbox positioning center instead of left

Tags: html, css

I am creating a sign in form and I added a remember me checkbox. For some reason I cannot get the checkbox to align left. It is centering in the middle of the form. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Also, side note...why is my submit button not the same size as my other input text boxes?

```css
#sign-in-form {
 width: 400px;
 height: auto;
 padding: 50px 30px;
 margin: auto;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: rgba(115,155,175,0.2);
}
#sign-in-form input {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 8px 6px;
 margin: 22px auto;
 display: block;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: none;
}
#sign-in-form input[type="checkbox"] {
 padding: 7px;
 text-align: left;
}
#sign-in-form input[type="submit"] {
 background: #4FCBFE;
 color: #FFF;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sign-in-form">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" autocomplete="on" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">Remember me</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `width` to `auto` and add `margin-left: 0`

```
#sign-in-form input[type="checkbox"] {
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Here is the working snippet.

```css
#sign-in-form {
 width: 400px;
 height: auto;
 padding: 50px 30px;
 margin: auto;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: rgba(115,155,175,0.2);
}
#sign-in-form input {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 8px 6px;
 margin: 22px auto;
 display: block;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: none;
}
#sign-in-form input[type="checkbox"] {
 padding: 7px;
 text-align: left;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#sign-in-form input[type="submit"] {
 background: #4FCBFE;
 color: #FFF;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sign-in-form">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" autocomplete="on" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">Remember me</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
   </div>
```

I think this is the result you are looking for:

```css
#sign-in-form {
 width: 400px;
 height: auto;
 padding: 50px 30px;
 margin: auto;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: rgba(115,155,175,0.2);
}
#sign-in-form input {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 8px 6px;
 margin: 22px auto;
 display: block;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: none;
}
#sign-in-form input[type="checkbox"] {
 padding: 7px;
 text-align: left;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
#sign-in-form input[type="submit"] {
 background: #4FCBFE;
 color: #FFF;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sign-in-form">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" autocomplete="on" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">Remember me</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can add padding to the box itself? So it appears larger?

Comment: added another snippet in the answer, let me know if this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Do you know how I can make the box itself larger? For instance, I added padding to the text inputs in order to make the input larger. 
How do I do the same for the checkbox?

Comment: If you are taking about the container you can change the width/height of `#sign-in-form`

Comment: No, I am referring to the checkbox. How do you make it bigger?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is remove the 100% width from the check box and also the auto margin, most importantly is adding `display: inline-block;` so that the **Remember me** text gets inline with the checkbox

Check the edited snippet below!

```css
#sign-in-form {
 width: 400px;
 height: auto;
 padding: 50px 30px;
 margin: auto;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: rgba(115,155,175,0.2);
}
#sign-in-form input {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 8px 6px;
 margin: 22px auto;
 display: block;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: none;
}
#sign-in-form input[type="checkbox"] {
 margin-right: 7px;
 text-align: left;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
#sign-in-form input[type="submit"] {
 background: #4FCBFE;
 color: #FFF;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sign-in-form">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" autocomplete="on" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">Remember me</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was happen because of you css property  #sign-in-form input {}. You can change it like this #sign-in-form input[type="text"],[type="password"],[type="submit"]{} . If you have any question ask me in comment. :)

```css
#sign-in-form {
width: 400px;
height: auto;
padding: 50px 30px;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 3px;
background: rgba(115,155,175,0.2);
}
#sign-in-form input[type="text"],[type="password"],[type="submit"] {
width: 100%;
padding: 8px 6px;
margin: 22px auto;
display: block;
font-size: 1.4em;
border-radius: 3px;
border: none;
}
#sign-in-form input[type="checkbox"] {
/*ADD YOUR CSS FOR CHECK BOX*/
}
#sign-in-form input[type="submit"] {
background: #4FCBFE;
color: #FFF;
border: none;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sign-in-form">
   <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" autocomplete="on" required>
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required>
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">Remember me</label>
   <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
   <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
  </div>
```